# How to know if a TextInput component is active in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, textinput

Imagine I have two TextInput components. How do I know which one is active, if any? Is there an event or a property that tells me that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [FocusManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/managers/FocusManager.html#includeExamplesSummary) class.